# Two variable files

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have two variable files that we don't want to merge. Is there any option to read both files? Can we add /vars/file02.yml somehow?

```
jobs:
- deployment: 
  environment: PROD
  displayName: "Deployment"
  pool: 'Windows'
  variables:
    - template: '/vars/File01.yml'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish it were possible. You can achieve this by using the variables' keyword, which seems to be used in your code itself. You just need to add an array for another file in same manner you did for file1.yaml

Here is revised code for same:

```
jobs:
- deployment: 
  environment: PROD
  displayName: "Deployment"
  pool: 'Windows'
  variables:
    - template: '/vars/File01.yml'
    - template: '/vars/File02.yml'
```

Make sure the path is correct.

Comment: If you have tried the above solution, then please update your question accordingly with error.